# Install ubuntu in ssd and use hdd for /home

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am sorry this is repetitive but I just couldn't find this particular question's answer. So I have a typical ssd and hdd setup in my laptop with windows and now I wanted to change to ubuntu. I was thinking of using ssd for root and swap, and hdd for home folder. Losing files in ssd is fine but I have some important data in hdd. My question is, will creating a home partition deletes all the existing file on hdd?

Comment: Will [this referece](https://www.howtogeek.com/442101/how-to-move-your-linux-home-directory-to-another-hard-drive/) help?

Answer (score 0):

**...will creating a home partition deletes all the existing file on hdd?**

Short answer is "yes". If you are going to replace Windows with Ubuntu (or any other operating system) then the data on both your SSD and HDD will be eliminated, new file systems will be created, and the computer will have none of your former data on it.

Before switching the computer to Ubuntu, you will want to make sure you have a good backup of your important files. This can be done with a USB stick, an external hard drive, cloud storage, or anything else that can support all of your data. Once the computer has a new operating system installed, you can copy everything back.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: You can shrink a NTFS partition and put /home in a separate ext4 partition. But if you leave Windows fast start up on which sets hibernation flag, then Linux NTFS driver cannot write into the NTFS data. And you cannot maintain NTFS from Linux. When it needs chkdsk or defrag you have to use Windows. Best to convert to Linux formats if removing Windows.